# Socket freezes when write is attempted

Tags: c, sockets, networking, tcp, ftp

I am writing a FTP server in C. Currently I am struggling with passive connection. I maintain a connection via sockets, and I have two of those. The first one is `const int a_socket`, it is created when a client connects and it accepts all client commands and sends response codes from the server. The second one is `int p_socket`, which is only connected when passive mode is requested by the client It is supposed to send large data. I get an error when I try to send anything through `p_socket` - the server gets stuck in the `write` function and the client (I am currently testing against Filezilla) recieves `ECONNRESET`. It also appears that the server is sending RST instead of the message.

I create the sockets with `create_socket`

```
int create_socket(int *ap_socket, const int a_port) {
    // variables
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    int yes = 1;

    // create address
    memset(&serverAddr, 0, sizeof(serverAddr));
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(a_port);

    // create socket
    if ((*ap_socket = socket(serverAddr.sin_family, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("service_create(): create socket");
        return 0;
    }

    // set options
    if (setsockopt(*ap_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) < 0) {
        perror("service_create(): socket opts");
        return 0;
    }

    // bind socket
    if (bind(*ap_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) < 0) {
        perror("service_create(): bind socket");
        close(*ap_socket);
        return 0;
    }

    // listen to socket
    if (listen(*ap_socket, SERVER_SOCKET_BACKLOG) < 0) {
        perror("service_create(): listen socket");
        close(*ap_socket);
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

The client connects without issues on both sockets, but only `a_socket` is able to send any data. I am using the following function to check the sockets.

```
int check_socket(const int sd) {
    int result = write(sd, "\0", 2);
    if (result >= 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I am using wireshark to view the packets and I do all of the testing on localhost. Socket `a_socket` connects client 
port 43684 to FTP port 21 on server (not seen in the log). Server provides port 20 for passive connection and client connects via port 50601.

Last three lines of the log show results of `check_socket`. Test message sent from `a_socket` (\000\000) arrives fine and is ACKned by the client, but the same message sent from `p_socket` results in RST right on the next line.

[image: Wireshark records]

I am not fluent in C and I am a beginner in sockets and networking, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the return value of the `write` call by the server when it fails? Also, you should consider using `send(2)` rather than `write(2)`.

Comment: It doesn't return at all. The server freezes right inside the function. I tried using `send` instead, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Do you mean that the server *blocks* on that call to `write(2)`? Can you run the code in a debugger? Either stop the code on that line and verify that everything looks OK, or, when the server hangs, interrupt the program to see what's slowing it down.

Comment: Yes, it enters `write` and never returns. Unfortunately, this doesn't happen when debugging. The debugger returns correctly and confirms that the socket is not ok.

Comment: What is the error returned from `write(2)`?

Comment: Both write and send return -1 for the p_socket

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. What is `errno` after the `write` call fails? Look at `perror(3)` or `strerror(3)` for ways to print this information.

Comment: Perror says I have a `Bad file descriptor`, which is something I can work with. Thank you for your help, I will have a look at this tomorrow.

Comment: The word you are looking for is not 'freezes' but 'blocks', but if you are getting EBADF your socket is neither freezing nor blocking.